# wrong webpage rendered on user error

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am currently writing a page of a website, and I have a function that renders a new webpage to tell the user that they made an error if the date they have selected is in the past. The function looks like this:

```
        if($interval < 0){
        handle_error($dbval_date_error2);
        }
```

If the user did put in a valid date, then the date is stored in a database and a new webpage is displayed which shows the new data entry.

The problem I have is that the handle_error function appears not to work usually. It functions exactly as it should if I also include some kind of print statement:

```
    if($interval < 0){
        handle_error($dbval_date_error2);
        echo "here";
    }
```

But if I just have the error function on its own, the function call just gets completely ignored and the entry gets stored in the database.

The error function looks like this:

```
function handle_error($error)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
    header('location:../register/register.php');
}
```

Comment: Where is `handle_error_big` defined?

Comment: Just as a quick note, the header doesn't appear to be constructed properly. Try this instead: `header('Location: ../register/register_small.php'); exit();` instead, and note the space after the Location colon.

Comment: @matthewrapati it's in a separate file which I include as such: include("../includes/dbconnect.php");

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how you're constructing your header; there needs to be a space between the colon and the path, Location needs to be uppercase, and you need to call `exit();` after you set the header.

```
function handle_error($error)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
    header('Location: ../register/register.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `exit()` after your `header()`:

```
function handle_error($error)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
    header('location:../register/register.php');
    exit();
}
```

And it should work